# What type of report has been created from JIRA?

Tags: testing, jira, manual-testing

JIRA tracking issues by creating reports. It shows total estimate of the project, how many time have been taken by a project. What should be the outcome of the project?

Now my question is: **What are the types of reports which have been generated in JIRA.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We can generate following reports in JIRA:

**1) Average Age Report:**
It shows that how many issues are pending or unsolved. Accordingly it will generate a report and give you the particular picture of the project about pending issues.

**2) Issue Created vs. Resolved Issues Report:**
By the name we can understand that it will create reports for created issues and resolved issues report which will display whole the scenario of the project and display the work done by the Team.

**3) Pie chart Report:**
It will display issues status with different colors so we can identify the project status or sprint status easily.

**4) Project Pivot Report:**
It shows that how much time has been taken by the users for verifying project for the specific period?

**5) Recently Created issue Report:**
It will display all the detail for recently created issues which shows that how many percentage of the project is completed and how many project is pending.

6) All the dead line of the project have been followed or not, all the issues are solved or it has in progress status this all can be verified by reports.

7) We can create **sprint report, Epic Report, Version Report, velocity chart, control chart, cumulative flow diagram** too.

> Progress Report has been shown from here:

[image: JIRA Progress]

*Blue line indicates ideal task remaining and red line indicates actual task remaining.*

> With the help of Pie chart we can see that different status have been displayed with different colors:

[image]

8) It also gives reports of Project status or Sprint status.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Average Age Report —** Shows the average age (in days) of unresolved issues.
**2) Created vs Resolved Issues Report —** Shows the number of issues created vs the number of issues resolved over a given period of time.
**3) Pie Chart Report —** Shows the search results from a specified issue filter (or project) in a pie-chart, based on a statistic of your choice.
**4) Resolution Time Report —** Shows the average time taken to resolve issues.
**5) Recently Created Issues Report —** Shows the rate at which issues are being created.
**6) Single Level Group By Report —** Shows the search results from an issue filter, grouped by a field of your choice.
**7) Time Since Issues Report —** Shows the number of issues for which your chosen date field (e.g. 'Created') was set on a given date.
**8) Time Tracking Report –** Shows time to track information on issues for a particular version of a project.
**9) User Workload Report * —** Shows how much work a user has been allocated, and how long it should take.
**10) Version Time Tracking Report * —** Shows progress towards completing a given version, based on issues' work logs and time estimates.
**11) Version Workload Report * —** Shows how much outstanding work there is (per user and per issue) before a given version is complete.
**12) Workload Pie Chart Report * —** Shows the relative workload for assignees of all issues in a particular project or issue filter.